# Filipino travelling to Phillippines via Turkey with 13hr Layover

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, transit-visas, turkey, filipino-citizens

I am going home for vacations to the Philippines and I took a Turkish Airline Flight with a layover of 18 hrs and it includes a change of airports. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Where do you live?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Philippines with a normal passport can obtain an e-visa before departure at www.evisa.gov.tr if they have
>     a valid on arrival visa or a residence permit issued by
>     Ireland (Rep.), USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member
>     State

So if you have a valid visa or residence permit from Schengen, the UK, Ireland or the US, you can get an eletronic entry permit [here](http://www.evisa.gov.tr).

Otherwise you need a visa.